# Не удалось установить SSL-соединение,

Tags: c#, хостинг, discord-api

Вообщем сделал для своего дискорд бота как здесь - http://legendminds.in/how-to-run-net-core-console-app-on-linux/ , только не много уточню у меня debian хостинг, но не суть важно, вообщем у меня выбивает такую ошибку [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

решил в RunBotAsync добавить код, по типу решения моей проблемы но не помогло

```
  class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args) => new Program().RunBotAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();

        private DiscordSocketClient _client;
        private CommandService _commands;
        private IServiceProvider _services;

        public async Task RunBotAsync()
        {
            _client = new DiscordSocketClient();
            _commands = new CommandService();

            _services = new ServiceCollection()
                .AddSingleton(_client)
                .AddSingleton(_commands)
                .BuildServiceProvider();

            string token = "";

            _client.Log += _client_Log;

            await RegisterCommandsAsync();

            await _client.LoginAsync(TokenType.Bot, token);

            await _client.StartAsync();

            await Task.Delay(-1);

            HttpClientHandler clientHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
            clientHandler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => { return true; };

           
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient(clientHandler);

        }

        private Task _client_Log(LogMessage arg)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(arg);
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        public async Task RegisterCommandsAsync()
        {
            _client.MessageReceived += HandleCommandAsync;
            await _commands.AddModulesAsync(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly(), _services);
        }

        private async Task HandleCommandAsync(SocketMessage arg)
        {
            var message = arg as SocketUserMessage;
            var context = new SocketCommandContext(_client, message);
            if (message.Author.IsBot) return;

            int argPos = 0;
            if (message.HasStringPrefix("!", ref argPos))
            {
                var result = await _commands.ExecuteAsync(context, argPos, _services);
                if (!result.IsSuccess) Console.WriteLine(result.ErrorReason);
                if (result.Error.Equals(CommandError.UnmetPrecondition)) await message.Channel.SendMessageAsync(result.ErrorReason);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Вставьте ошибку текстом, пожалуйста.

Comment: @aepot полностью?

Comment: Ну да, а как еще? Ограничьте текстовый блок символами ``` сверху и снизу

Comment: Кстати, код `Main` у вас блокирует стартовый поток, при чем зря, попробуйте так `static Task Main(string[] args) => new Program().RunBotAsync();`. Это не относится к вашей проблеме, а просто совет.

Comment: `HttpClientHandler` и `HttpClientHandler` - это вообще зачем в коде `RunBotAsync`?  Вы просто здесь создаете `HttpClient`, и никак его не используете.

Comment: Какая целевая платформа? Framework, Core, версия?

Comment: @aepot core, я не знаю как правильно использовать HttpClient

Comment: Смотря для чего он вам понадобился.

Comment: [Говорят](https://github.com/discord-net/Discord.Net/issues/1356), что вам нужно собрать приложение из исходников прямо на сервере вместо того, чтобы выкладывать его как self-contained. А `HttpClient` уберите из кода, оно здесь ни к чему.

Comment: @aepot а 2 вопроса как собрать приложение из исходников прямо на сервере, и если бы у меня была операционная система ubuntu на хостинге этой проблемы не было?

Comment: Это уже [другой вопрос](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-debian).

Comment: @aepot просто если это проблема debian, то я бы купил бы ubuntu если и с ubuntu такая же проблема будет, то тогда пойду пробовать фиксить

Comment: Проблемы в разных юниксах могут быть разные. У меня вообще серевер FreeBSD, официально не поддерживаемая ОС в .NET Core 3.1. Но изрядно повозившись, я заставил всё работать. В юниксах нет таких проблем, которые невозможно решить, но иногда приходится сильно постараться, чтобы добиться нужного результата. В любом случае, ваша проблема слишком абстрактная, чтобы решать ее здесь.

Comment: @aepot на убунту всё прекрасно работает, уже просто нету сил радоваться ибо вчера 20 часов в фулл фокусе пытался пофиксить а это оказалась проблема ОС

Comment: @aepot а ещё ласт вопрос я вот скомпилил бота в putty но почему когда я прогу закрываю он у меня не работает я же залил проект на хостинг и скомпилил

Comment: Потому что вы его запускаете в режиме приложения от имени консоли. Если по-простому, то добавьте в конец строки запуска через пробел символ `&`. Если по-нормальному, запускайте как [демон](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10068950/12888024).

Comment: @aepot спасибки вы 3 человек кто помог мне на ру стаковерфлоу))